# SPARK In Memory Computation

Tags: rdd, in-memory

If Spark computes all its RDD operations in-memory itself, then what difference does it make to persist RDD in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can persist RDD to apply more than one action or call  action on RDD later on. After persist the RDD spark will Skip all the the stages which are need to me calculated for execution of Action. In spark all transformations are lazy evaluated that means when you call action all transformations will be executed in real so at first time if you call collect() its will execute all transformation and persist one of the RDD now if you again run another action like count it will not re-execute all transformation just skip all before persist and execute non persisted part for example

```
val list = sc.parallelize(List(1,23,5,4,3,2))
val rdd1 = list.map(_+1)
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_+5).cache
rdd2.collect
rdd2.count
```

like in the above example when rdd2.collect will call it will executed all above transformations as you notice rdd2 is already cache so now when count will be call it will not execute above transformation and use persisted rdd to calculate results.